# Move SharePoint 2010 designer list workflow from one server to another server

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow, migration

I have created SharePoint 2010 designer list workflow.

Could you please give me suggestion on how to move the SharePoint 2010 designer list workflow from one server to another?

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the list as a template.
2. Download the list template.
3. Import the list template to the other farm and activate it as a feature.
4. Create a list from that template.

The new list will have the workflows.

Answer (score 0):

Saving the list as a template will not copy the workflows with the list.
So you have to copy the workflows independently and later you have to associate this workflows to respective lists.

you can see the following for how to move the SP 2010 workflows.
[a link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meamcs/2012/04/22/solved-moving-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflows-between-sites/)

Comment: does this answers your question?